# Is there any way to store or update a file to One-drive after Jenkins build run?

Tags: jenkins, onedrive

Is there any way to store or update a CSV file to One-drive after Jenkins build run? I want it to happen without any third-party plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [OneDrive API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_put_content) and `curl`, e.g.:

```sh
curl https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/data.csv:/content -X PUT -d @data.csv -H "Authorization: bearer access_token_here"
```

One limitation is that your `csv` file couldn't be more than 4MB.